# How can I change the "Cloud storage Staging Bucket" of an existing Dataproc cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I have one `Dataproc` cluster, and its `Cloud Storage staging bucket` is set to a bucket that no longer exists (was made just for testing purposes). There is another bucket that we wish to use instead. How would I connect this cluster to that bucket? I am very new to the Google Cloud Platform so any additional overarching conceptual information would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not providing a bucket of your own and instead let Dataproc create and manage one for you. This happens automatically when you omit `--bucket` flag.

Benefit of letting Dataproc manage buckets for you is buckets are created in correct storage regions.

Comment: would I have to create a new dataproc cluster and omit the `--bucket` flag during creation in order for it manage one for me?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to create a new cluster. The only way for us to update a bucket on existing cluster is via a support ticket.